# ReactiveUI: How to pass a parameter to ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask correctly

Tags: reactiveui

I want to pass a parameter from my View to my ViewModel when a  ReactiveCommand is executed that is bound to a Control. The parameter should be of type `IJcUser`

So I define the Command like this:

```
public ReactiveCommand<IJcUser, Unit> UserTouchCommand;

UserTouchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(user => RootViewModel.DisplayUserProfile(user));
```

The signature of `DisplayUserProfile`looks like

`Task DisplayUserProfile(IJcUser user);`

But the compiler complains because `user`is from type `CancelationToken`and not as expected `IJcUser`

I finally I found a solution but don't understand why the first approach did not work.

```
UserTouchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<IJcUser>(RootViewModel.DisplayUserProfile);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I finally I found a solution but don't understand why the first approach did not work.

Because you are using the wrong overload of the `ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask` method. The delegate `user => RootViewModel.DisplayUserProfile(user)` may be a `Func<CancellationToken, Task>` or a `Func<IJcUser, Task>`. The compiler cannot know which one unless you tell it:

```
Func<IJcUser, Task> x = user => DisplayUserProfile(user);
UserTouchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(x);
```

Or you could be explicit about the type argument:

```
UserTouchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<IJcUser>(DisplayUserProfile);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be able to get this from the Command declaration?

Comment: No. As mentioned, how is it supposed to know that your func is a Func<IJcUser, Task> rather than a Func<CancellationToken, Task> or Func<Something, Task> unless you tell it? It can't.

Comment: Very helpful for me to pass a parameter to `ReactiveCommond.CreateFromTask`. ReactiveUI makes it very confusing here (lots of overloaded types, type deductions, and optional parameters) and always makes me feel desperate.